# How to get all documents in a firestore subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've currently got a firestore that looks like **this**:

```
Collection('machines').doc(*machineID*).collection('reports').doc(*multiple docs reports*)
```

I'm using `Vue`, and I'm trying to get all the documents in the 'reports' collection.

I can get a single **report**:

```
reports: firebase.firestore()
  .collection('machine')
  .doc('machine_01')
  .collection('report')
  .doc('report_05')
```

But I can't get the **subcollection** as a whole

```
reports: firebase.firestore()
  .collection('machine')
  .doc('machine_01')
  .collection('report')
```

Is this possible? I am new to this, so this may be a silly question.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
The error message I'm getting in the console is:

```
index.cjs.js?e89a:350 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:350:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:14844:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:15335:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:11305:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:11234:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:11274:28)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:1634:20)
```

I'm not sure about the permissions, I don't have access to them, but if it's a permission issue, I'm confused that I can get a single document from the collection, but can't find a way of getting all the documents

Comment: The `Missing or insufficient permissions` error means that you don't have permission to read the data. You'll need to allow the user to access the data in the Firebase security rules for your database.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure: "A read rule can be broken into get and list".

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a `Missing or insufficient permissions` error. Looks like the user does not have access to your DB information; therefore, I would try to do the following:

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
     }
  }
}
```

More info **[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)**